# Java code to convert decimal to hexadecimal with Bitwise operators

Tags: java, loops, hex, bitwise-operators

I have this code to convert decimal to hexadecimal, but I need it to work for numbers greater than 255.

```
        int v = 13;
        String hexV = ""; 
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) { 
            int rem = v & 15;
            v = (byte)(v >> 4); 
            hexV = "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(rem) + hexV;
        }
        System.out.println("V: " + hexV);
```

This code works great for numbers up until 255 but I need it to work for a much larger range. Given this code, how can I change it to work for larger numbers? Specifically the range (-524288 - 524287). I don't want to use toHexString or methods similar, I'm just trying to work with the code that I'm given.

I've tried changing the loop from i<2 to i<3 up to i<6 to accommodate for the extra places in the hexadecimal conversion but the result is never accurate. Usually the last two digits are correct and the rest of it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Run the loop until `v` becomes `0` and remove the cast to `byte`.

```java
String hexV = ""; 
while (v > 0) { 
    int rem = v & 15;
    v >>= 4; 
    hexV = "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(rem) + hexV;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for the 5 and 6 digit numbers. The output is only displaying 3 digits when there should be 4 or 5. How can I print the whole hexadecimal number?

Comment: @happyHorse349 I cannot reproduce the issue. Did you copy the code over properly? It works fine for me: https://ideone.com/QuqP5A